# Vanilla JavaScript event delegation when dealing with Web Components

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, event-delegation

My current project uses web components (Custom Elements and Shadow DOM) which allow me to encapsulate complex logic and styles away from the Light DOM.

Unfortunately, I've now hit a snag where I need to be able to switch out elements at will without the hassle of unbinding and rebinding event handlers.

This sounds like a job for event delegation to me so I tried adding an event listener to a parent node in the Light DOM hoping that the event would bubble up from the Shadow DOM.

This seems to go against the encapsulation of the Shadow DOM and the event.target is always the ShadowRoot and never a child.

Is there something I can do to allow classic event delegation in this situation? The code snippet below shows the problem. I want to be able to click the inner DIV and handle the click in the click event handler but the event.target is always the custom-el

```js
/* jshint esversion: 6 */

customElements.define('custom-el', class extends HTMLElement {

 constructor() {
  super();

  this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
   mode: 'open'
  });

  const oInnerDiv = document.createElement('div');
  oInnerDiv.classList.add('inner');
    oInnerDiv.style.border = '2px solid blue';
    oInnerDiv.style.padding = '3rem';
  this._shadowRoot.appendChild(oInnerDiv);
 }

});

document.addEventListener('click', oEvent => {
 document.getElementById('result').innerText = oEvent.target.tagName;
}, true);
```

```css
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

main,
div,
custom-el {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid black;
 padding: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <custom-el>
</main>
  
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: I don't how standard it is, but you can have access to it in `oEvent.path[0]` in Chrome (do other browsers support ShadowDOM?)

Comment: I believe Safari does and FF has it behind a flag (due to standardise in v63).
Nothing from Edge yet

Comment: AFK right now. once again I don't know for standards. FF exposes a  [Event.explicitOriginalTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/explicitOriginalTarget) property, which might leak this info? For Safari, IDK...

Comment: Have you tried Mid DOM mediation?

Comment: So I got back to a keyboard and indeed, FF 63 does leak through `oEvent.explicitOriginalTarget`, Safari on the other hand doesn't seem to provide any means to access it like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the shadow DOM mode is `open`, it is possible to get the inner element clicked with the help of the [`Event.composedPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) method, which will return the array of the nodes crossed (innest node first).

```
document.addEventListener('click', oEvent => {
    result.innerText = oEvent.composedPath()[0].tagName;
}, true);
```

This method replaces the old `Event.path` property.

```js
customElements.define('custom-el', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    const oInnerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    oInnerDiv.classList.add('inner');
    oInnerDiv.style.border = '2px solid blue';
    oInnerDiv.style.padding = '1rem';
  this._shadowRoot.appendChild(oInnerDiv);      
  }
});

document.addEventListener('click', oEvent => {
  result.innerText = oEvent.composedPath()[0].tagName;
});
```

```css
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

main,
div,
custom-el {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid black;
 padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <custom-el></custom-el>
</main>
  
<p id="result"></p>
```